# What's an appropriate word for "timestrip"

Tags: word-choice

I'm not a native English speaker and I have to describe a certain scenario or a component that actually represents a strip of time. This strip would actually look similar to this with some point on it:

```
|00:00    |01:00   |02:00   |03:00   |04:00 ....
|___________________________________________ _ _
|
|___________________________________________ _ _
```

I have to write formal documentation but don't know what would be the best name for this kind of visual representation of time. I feel that using **timestrip** may not be best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a [*timeline*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/timeline).

> A graphical representation of a chronological sequence of events (past or future); a chronology.

Comment: Thank you very much. **Exactly** what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm accustomed to using **timebands** to refer to specific subsections within timelines.